# Flask button generated with wtforms not triggering POST request

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm writing a Flask application that works sort of like a blog. I generated the text boxes with wtforms, but whenever I click on the button to save the text, nothing happens. I get no errors.

I've tried adding print statements to my code, and everything is working fine except that Flask is not receiving the POST request. Clicking the button does absolutely nothing.

This is the code for the endpoint. I added a print() statement after if request.method but nothing printed out, so I'm assuming it's not receiving the POST request:

```
@app.route("/newtext", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def newtext():
    form = NewPost()
    if request.method == "POST" and form.validate():
        new_post = Texts(user_id=current_user.id, title=form.title.data, content=form.content.data)
        db.session.add(new_post)
        db.session.commit()
        new_click = UserActions(user_id=current_user.id, action=4)
        db.session.add(new_click)
        db.session.commit()
        last_text = db.session.query(Texts).order_by(Texts.id.desc()).first()
        text_id = last_text.id
        text_version = TextVersions(content=form.content.data, user_id=current_user.id, text_id=text_id)
        db.session.add(text_version)
        db.session.commit()
        plaintext = BeautifulSoup(form.content.data)
        text_summary = Grammar.summary(plaintext.get_text())
        return render_template("summary.html", text_id=text_id, text_summary=text_summary)
    else:
        return render_template("basiceditor.html", form=form)
```

And this is the html code for the webpage. It renders okay (the GET method clearly works) but the button does nothing:

```
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST" action="/newtext">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">{{ legend }}</legend>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.title.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {% if form.title.errors %}
                        {{ form.title(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.title.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.title(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.content.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {% if form.content.errors %}
                        {{ form.content(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.content.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.content(class="form-control form-control-lg", id="controleditor") }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-success") }}
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The app reports no errors. It should save the text to the database and send the person to the summary.html page, but clicking on the button does nothing. I am completely stumped.

Comment: A couple things that may help with troubleshooting:  
1. Try print `form.errors` to see if there are errors you're not showing on the form fields.  
2.  Pass `request` into the form to pre-populate data in the form if there have been errors: `form = NewPost(request)`
Also, you can replace `if request.method == "POST" and form.validate():` with just `if form.validate_on_submit():`

Comment: Thanks! I tried printing form.errors and nothing happened. I also had originally put if form.validate.on.submit() but it wasn't working either, which is why I changed it to see if it helped any. I haven't tried the form = NewPost(request) so I'll give that a try.

Comment: Have u put csrf token to the html file?